# How to print page in IE,Edge with background colors

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

We recently discovered a bug, where IE and Edge do not correctly print a page. By this, I mean background colours are not displayed correctly and some elements are not formatted correctly.

I have looked at other posts and answers referring to `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`, but that is only for Chrome and has no effect.

Some sites also mentioned the show background colours option in IE and edge, but that does not seem to be an option anymore, as the option has been removed.

This was working up to about a week ago, so I'm assuming it's a Windows update thing, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Pleasae define "_colours are not displayed correctly_". So you see only the shades of grey, or black and white only, or are there no colors at all? Or do you mean you see red as blue or something like that? Also, IE hasn't been updated for years, it still has the option for printing background and colors.

Comment: Okay, so the issue was the background settings in IE, thanks for the help. Just to clarify, elements with background-color were being printed, but just not their colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IE browser, click the Tools button, point to Print, and then click Page setup. Under Paper Options, select the **Print Background Colors and Images** check box, and then click OK. Like this:

[image]

Then, try to preview the print page, the screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa6sv.png).

Besides, it seems that there does not appear to be a way to print background colors (highlighting) on the Microsoft Edge browser. You could try to open the page in IE browser, then print the page.